# contiki C++ compile causes region `FLASH_CCA' overflowed for zoul

Tags: c++, c, contiki

I need to compile a C++ library to use with contiki on the Zolertia Re-Mote. I am trying a simple program first:

#### hello-world.c

```
#include "contiki.h"

#include "misc.h"
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(hello_world_process, "Hello world process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&hello_world_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(hello_world_process, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  say_hello();

  PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

#### misc.cpp

```
/* C++ implementation */
#ifdef CONTIKI_TARGET_ZOUL
void* __dso_handle;
void* __exidx_end;
void* __exidx_start;
#endif

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void cpp_say_hello(){
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}

/* C wrapper */
extern "C"{
    #include "misc.h"

    void say_hello(){
        cpp_say_hello();
    }
}
```

#### misc.h

```
#ifndef _MISC_H_
#define _MISC_H_

/**
 * \brief Prints hello to stdout
 */
void say_hello();

#endif /* _MISC_H_ */
```

#### Makefile

```
ifeq ($(TARGET),)
    TARGET = native
endif

CONTIKI_PROJECT = hello-world
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

PROJECT_LIBRARIES = obj_$(TARGET)/misc.o

include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include

obj_$(TARGET)/misc.o: misc.cpp
    @mkdir -p obj_$(TARGET)
    $(TRACE_CXX)
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

This (with some modifications to the contiki Makefiles: [here](https://github.com/wellsaid/contiki/commit/b9d0f8b499479e7315d5841aaa038a76d1b13adb)) made possible for me to use C++ code for the 'native' target. However when i try to compile for the Zolertia Re-Mote platform (TARGET=zoul) i obtain the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: hello-world.elf section `.ARM.extab.text._Z13cpp_say_hellov' will not fit in region `FLASH_CCA'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: region `FLASH_CCA' overflowed by 788 bytes
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/wellsaid/contiki/cpu/cc2538/Makefile.cc2538:103: hello-world.elf] Error 1
rm hello-world.co obj_zoul/startup-gcc.o
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: The error message appears to be telling you that the compiled code is too large for the target device.  In that case, you might try compiler options to optimize for small code size.  Since you appear to be using GCC, that would be `-Os`, and be careful to avoid overriding the effects of that via other optimization flags.

Comment: In general, C++ is not supported on Contiki. In particular (your example), the problem most likely is the iostream library - it's too large to fit on the flash.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, that doesn't seem to make difference. I've tried to add it in CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS

Comment: More likely, `-Os` doesn't make *enough* difference to solve the problem.  And if that's so then now may be a good time to throw in the towel.  It is conceivable that you could find or build a small enough implementation of the C++ standard library that the needed bits would fit, together with your own code, into the target device, but that effort would probably be better spent on converting your C++ library of interest instead, or to finding an alternative.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It does not make a difference because it is already the default optimization level for the target platform.